# Create React App fails when "Starting the development server"

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

My react application is built using create react app https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html fails to start.

When i exec `npm run start` my application hangs with the following message.

> Starting the development server...

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^13.7.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.19",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "npm-check-updates": "^4.0.1",
    "qs": "^6.9.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@semantic-release/gitlab": "^6.0.2",
    "semantic-release": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "release": {
    "branch": "master",
    "plugins": [
      "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
      "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
      [
        "@semantic-release/gitlab",
        {
          "gitlabUrl": "https://git.companyname.com"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Node Version: `v12.14.1`
Npm Version: `6.13.4`

I have tried this a few times and each time it fails it is creating a new node process i know this because it asks me to select a different port.

So far i have attempted the following process without any luck

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
npm start
```

Comment: Have you tried to visit localhost:3000?

Comment: Yes i have tried to visit localhost:port (3000) and the page is continuously loading forever

Comment: check your browser console

Comment: Try:
`npm install npm@latest -g`

Comment: @demkovych Nothing in the console of relevance, the page does not finish loading so im not sure what you'd expect

Comment: Did you change webpack config?

Comment: @demkovych No, and as far as im aware when building an app using create-react-app it does not expose a webpack file.

Comment: try to clean your npm cache `npm start -- --reset-cache` or `npm cache clear --force`

Comment: as a temporary workaround you can try decrease a version of react-scripts: `"react-scripts": "^2.1.8"`

Comment: @demkovych Niether of those reset cache commands worked.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen I tried updating npm and it did not help.

Comment: @Kay, In browser console what error do you see when try to open http://localhost:3000

Why is `react`, `react-dom` and `react-router-dom` imported twice? Try removing mentioned imports with `@type/...` and adding `/node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start` to your start script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it turned out restarting my computer fixed it.

I still don't know the cause of this as the environment has remained the same and apart from removing node_modules and npm install i did nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed some packages yourself after creating react application using creat-react-app, it may be because, one of the installed packages is not working.
In the past, I had a problem like your case.
At that time, I have installed react-pdf package to show pdfs.
As a consequence, development server didn't start and whenever I run again it asked to choose another port.
After removing that package, it worked well.

So I think there may be not working module in the package.json.
In my opinion, it may be 'qs' packagae.

Comment: I uninstalled qs and exec npm run start but it did not work

Comment: The qs dependency is up to date and installs fine (npm 6.13.7 and node v8/v12) It's not likely to be the issue IMHO.

Comment: I said may be. Of course that package can not be 'qs'. But I am sure that error comes from wrong package you have installed. I think you can find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your `package.json` file and ran it locally on my machine.

First I ran `npm install`

I then created `/src/index.js` and chucked in the following default code from create-react-app:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(<div>We're in!</div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And I also created /public/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Lastly, I ran `npm start`

The application ran fine, with the only concern being an out of date sub-dependency (Old version of corejs)

This leads me to think that the problem might be in your local setup.

I would recommend clearing your npm cache and trying again.

To clear your cache, run `npm cache clear --f` with elevated permissions.

My suggestion would then be to start a new app directory, just in case there's something corrupt in the existing directory.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing a previous version of npm-scripts
Try using this:

```
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
```